How to fix mouse movement selecting input text
I have a problem where when i move the mouse on the when typing in a input it selects the text and then when i type more it just overwrites it. Im using react, radixui and shadcn
Video Evidence
CODE

export default function Enrolled() {

    const info = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
  return (
   <div>
    {info.map(x => {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    <DropdownMenu>
                        <DropdownMenuTrigger>
                            Open
                        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
                        <DropdownMenuContent>
                            <DropdownMenuItem onSelect={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                               <Item/>
                            </DropdownMenuItem>
                        </DropdownMenuContent>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    })}
   </div>
  )
}


function Item() {
    return (
        <Dialog>
            <DialogTrigger>
                click me
            </DialogTrigger>
            <DialogContent>
                <input type="text" />
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}


It's because your Dialog is inside the DropdownMenu.
You should wrap your DropdownMenu with Dialog. Inside the DropdownMenuItem you add the DialogTrigger. Outside DropdownMenu, but inside Dialog you put your DialogContent
Example:
<Dialog>
   <DropdownMenu>
      ...
      <DropdownMenuItem><DialogTrigger>Trigger</DialogTrigger></DropdownMenuItem>
   </DropdownMenu>
   <DialogContent>...</DialogContent>
</Dialog>

More detail:
Shadcn Dialog inside of Dropdown closes automatically
